# Verify that user email is unique in test-unit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I a newbie in test-unit . I need to verify that email of the user is unique in the users table

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @usuario = User.new
    @usuario.email="pepe@hotmail.com"
    @usuario.password="123456"
  end 

  test "user email must be unique" do

  end    
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to verify that an email address that you just set in your test is unique? Don't you want to test that your model ensures that email addresses are unique as part of its own validation?

Comment: Are you essentially trying to verify that if a user already has signed up with a particular email, they can't sign up again with the same email? If so I'd start by  making the test say: 

test "user email must be unique" do

Comment: yes. that I want to do. I have to create other user with the same email for test that?. here the primary key is email

Comment: This really isn't something you should test manually as @smathy mentioned, this should be part of your model validation for email. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your other comment, this is how I'd do it:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  setup do
    @attrs = { email: "something@here.com", password: "123456" }
  end

  test "user email must be unique" do
    assert User.create(@attrs)
    assert user = User.new(@attrs)
    assert user.invalid?
    assert user.errors.include?(:email)
  end
end
```